# Rename a Docker Checkpoint

Tags: docker, docker-checkpoint

Is it possible to rename a docker checkpoint after it has been created? It seems like you should be able to, given that you can rename a container. However, I can't find any information or questions related to it.

I would like to be able to create a checkpoint, without worrying what to call it, and then come back later and give it an appropriate name.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the current Docker Engine API [v1.30](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.30/) (and therefore, by extension, the CLI) does not support renaming a checkpoint.

However, note that a checkpoint is essentially just a collection of files stored in a folder called

```
/var/lib/docker/containers/<container_id>/checkpoints/<checkpoint_name>
```

So, if you really need to rename the checkpoint, you can rename the folder:

```
$ export id=$(docker run -d --name redis redis)
$ docker checkpoint create redis old_checkpoint_name
$ mv /var/lib/docker/containers/$id/checkpoints/old_checkpoint_name /var/lib/docker/containers/$id/checkpoints/new_checkpoint_name
$ docker start --checkpoint new_checkpoint_name redis
```

Comment: I finally got around to testing this! When I rename the checkpoint my docker container doesn't seem to register the change and still shows the old checkpoint when I run $docker checkpoint ls <container_name>. I've stopped and started it to no avail